# When i open link in Device Application is crash after few second?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am using a `UIWebView`

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
[self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.webView setDelegate:self];
[self.webView setOpaque:NO];
```

**My application crash before calling the delegate**

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

**My error **

Receive Memory Warning

Comment: Update your question with error log.

Comment: Did you test with a single app, with only a UIWebView to see if you receive a MemoryWarning ? Firstly, did you test with a "simple" webpage ?